# How do I checkout a single folder from git

Tags: git

How do I checkout just a single folder from git (e.g. the jsFiles folder over [here](http://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/jstests/))

Comment: Same thing was asked in e.g. [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180052/checkout-subdirectories-in-git)...

Comment: @VonC: did you mean to say they have no place on SU and should be moved to SO? (I just figured I'd point out the duplicate in case other people wanted to migrate it or something)

Comment: @David: good point. That would be because Git questions have no place on SU and should all be moved on SO. See meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/61720

Comment: @David: right, I have deleted my previous comment ;)

Comment: Note: the right MSO reference for moving Git question from SU to SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61720

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a recent Git 1.7 install.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.0.4
$ git clone http://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git
$ cd mongo
$ git config core.sparsecheckout true
$ echo jstests >.git/info/sparse-checkout 
$ git read-tree -m -u HEAD
$ ls
jstests
```

Comment: doesn't your `git clone` checkout the whole repo first? I think the OP wanted to avoid that

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler, you can clone it bare, convert to non-bare and do a spare-checkout. But you can't avoid cloning the whole tree.