# Set Git submodule to shallow clone & sparse checkout?

Tags: git, clone, git-submodules, sparse-checkout, shallow-clone

Many vendor Objective-C libraries (e.g., `facebook-ios-sdk`) instruct you to copy a certain subset of its repo's files/dirs into your Xcode project. One problem with this is then you do not know what revision of the vendor code you have. Another is that if you make changes to the vendor code, it's not easy to contribute your changes via Git.

As a solution, I want to add each vendor library as a Git submodule of my project's repo with some extra settings (say, in the `.gitmodules` file). This way, if another person clones my project and does `git submodule update --init`, their repo & submodules will have the same state as mine because they'll be using the same default settings I set:

1. Sparse checkout: Only check out certain files of the submodule.
2. Shallow clone: Only clone a certain SHA1 of the submodule.

How do I set the above settings for a Git submodule?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but you could commit a script like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144406/git-shallow-submodules

Comment: Note that `git submodule` now can perform a **custom update**: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17693008/6309)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With [git1.8.4 (July 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt), in [addition git shallow update for submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17692710/6309) (`git submodule update --depth 1`), you now can have a **custom update**:

> In addition to the choice from "rebase, merge, or checkout-detach", "submodule update" can allow a custom command to be used in to update the working tree of submodules via the "`submodule.*.update`" configuration variable.

See [commit 6cb5728c43f34a7348e128b44b80d00b9417cb19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cb5728c43f34a7348e128b44b80d00b9417cb19):

> Users can set `submodule.$name.update` to '`!command`' which will cause '`command`' to be run instead of checkout/merge/rebase.
>   This allows the user finer-grained control over how the update is done.
>
> Signed-off-by: Chris Packham `<judge.packham@gmail.com>`

That means you can version a '`command`' that you can then use for any submodule update (through the `submodule.$name.update` setting).
That script can do a sparse checkout if you want.

---

Update August 2016 (3 years later)

With Git 2.10 (Q3 2016), you will be able to do

```
 git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<name>.shallow bool
```

See "[Git submodule without extra weight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38895397/6309)" for more.

Comment: VonC, but exactly what command do you then suggest to do the sparse checkout? I have no idea what it is.

Comment: @ThomasVanderStichele a script that would perform a sparse checkout, similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2340860/6309

Comment: `!command` does not work anymore: “Note that the !command form is intentionally ignored here for security reasons.”

Comment: @saji in which context/OS/policy do you see ! (shell execute) ignored for security reason?

Comment: @VonC My bad. It seems that `!command` form in `submodule.<name>.update` is not allowed in [`gitmodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules), but [is fine](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cb5728c43f34a7348e128b44b80d00b9417cb19#diff-08d0168d2216294c4f9de46cbb36bfcb) in “regular” config files.Which makes sense as `.gitmodules` is commited and `.git/config` is not.

Answer (score 23):

You can do sparse checkouts of submodules the same way as [normal sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180052/checkout-subdirectories-in-git). Just remember the `sparse-checkout` file for each module goes in `.git/modules/<mymodule>/info/`. But, as discussed in [git 1.7 sparse checkout feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0), sparse checkouts are exactly that: checkouts. You can't move files or share the settings.

Comment: +1 for a good solution (thanks @takoi). Create a submodule, then filter the files/dirs that appear in the working tree using the sparse checkout feature. There is a simple how to on Sparse checkout at http://blog.quilitz.de/2010/03/checkout-sub-directories-in-git-sparse-checkouts

Comment: @johnhunter Link is dead

Comment: there is a version of the blog on the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20150819045120/http://blog.quilitz.de/2010/03/checkout-sub-directories-in-git-sparse-checkouts

Answer (score -1):

Submodules can't do *part* of a repo.  You should check out [subtree merge](http://help.github.com/subtree-merge/) instead.

Comment: This comment is about an old version of git so it is not longer valid