# Subdirectory from github as a git submodule

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

A lots of repos for python on github use project structure for setuptools (for example https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth). 
But I want to make folder with module core to my project as a submodule.
Can I use subdirectories from remote repo as a submodule in my repo?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I want to make folder with module core to my project as a submodule"?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `sparse checkout` along with submodules.

[Set Git submodule to shallow clone & sparse checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238590/set-git-submodule-to-shallow-clone-sparse-checkout)