# Update git submodules shallowly with the '--depth' option

Tags: git, git-submodules

`git submodule update` has supported the `--depth` option as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17692710/1297064).

But still we can't easily determine the depth value, which would probably make git unable to find the intended revision of a submodule.

Is there a true solution for updating submodules shallowly?

Comment: It shouldn't prevent git to fetch the right depth. But if it was, then same comment as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294361/make-a-shallow-git-repository-less-shallow#comment37554751_24294361: (for git 1.9.x+) Did you try a git fetch --update-shallow in it (through a custom command/update maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17693008/6309).

Comment: I would first test the `git submodule update --depth` first: it should be able to update to the right depth, depending on recorded SHA1.

Comment: As of git 2.0.0, `--depth` must be followed by a value. So I think the exact depth would still be a myth, which is the only and must be resolved concern of the question. Thanks for help @VonC

Answer (score 6):

> So I think the exact depth would still be a myth, which is the only and must be resolved concern of the question

While there is indeed no "exact depth", you can still record a "depth recommendation" with git 2.9.x+ (Q3 2016).

See [commit abed000](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abed000acafd8aa86e02bcbb65fc1a8e4f06b8a0), [commit 37f52e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37f52e93441e1da00c9c9824ed03cd074d77f43a) (26 May 2016) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3807098](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3807098cd6abf4b94b6e0326255e5f5f0577f975), 20 Jun 2016)</sup>

> ### `submodule update`: learn `--[no-]recommend-shallow` option

> An upstream project can make a recommendation to shallowly clone some submodules in the `.gitmodules` file it ships.
>
> Sometimes the history of a submodule is not considered important by the projects upstream.
> To make it easier for downstream users, allow a boolean field '`submodule.<name>.shallow`' in `.gitmodules`, which can be used to recommend whether upstream considers the history important.
>
> This field is honored in the initial clone by default, it can be ignored by giving the `--no-recommend-shallow` option.

That way, a simple `git submodule update` (no additional parameters) will use the recommended depth value, if found.

See also "[Git submodule without extra weight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38895397/6309)" with:

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<name>.shallow true
```

---

[g19fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496405/g19fanatic) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677295/update-git-submodules-shallowly-with-the-depth-option/37933909?noredirect=1#comment113188277_37933909):

> quick 1-liner to add `shallow=true` to all submodules:
>
> ```bash
> git submodule | awk '{print $2}' | \
>   xargs -n 1 -I %% bash -c 'git config -f .gitmodules submodule.%%.shallow true'
> ```
>
> or, with [`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt):
>
> ```bash
> git submodule foreach 'git config -f .gitmodules submodule.$sm_path.shallow true'
> ```

However, [akhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828885/akhan) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677295/update-git-submodules-shallowly-with-the-depth-option/37933909?noredirect=1#comment134025613_37933909):

> The `foreach` command is executed from the submodules and hence will not work as described here (try `git submodule foreach 'echo $PWD'` for instance).
>
> However the `xargs` works just fine.
>
> Working recipe:
>
> ```bash
> git submodule | awk '{print $2}' | \
>  xargs -n 1 -I %% bash -c 'git config -f .gitmodules submodule.%%.shallow true' 
> git submodule update --depth=1
> ```

Comment: quick 1-liner to add shallow=true to all submodules `git submodule | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1 -I %% bash -c 'git config -f .gitmodules submodule.%%.shallow true'`

Comment: @g19fanatic Thank you. That should come in handy indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @g19fanatic But I believe using [`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt) is safer and does not need to rely on awk and other parsing tricks.

Comment: probably right. never really used foreach but awk/xargs are in my utility belt. for completeness `git submodule foreach 'git config -f .gitmodules submodule.$sm_path.shallow true'`

Comment: @g19fanatic And yet, as they say: "[This is the way](https://www.magicalquote.com/seriesquotes/this-is-the-way/)".

Comment: @VonC The `foreach` command is executed from the submodules and hence will not work as described here (try `git submodule foreach 'echo $PWD'` for instance). However the xargs works just fine. Working recipe: `git submodule | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1 -I %% bash -c 'git config -f .gitmodules submodule.%%.shallow true'` followed by `git submodule update --depth=1`

Comment: @akhan Good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

As of early 2024 the following command is accepted by **git 2.43.0**:

```
git submodule update --init --depth 1
```