# Git shallow fetch a few tags

Tags: git, fetch, tags

Following up on [Git shallow fetch of a new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617862/git-shallow-fetch-of-a-new-tag) and what I want is to

Git shallow fetch a few tags

- My git repo has latest tags from `1.5.1` to `1.5.8`.
- After git shallow clone, `git tag -l` gives no tags in output
- and I want to fetch a few of the latest tags, say from `1.5.5` to `1.5.8`.

How to do that please?

More on this, hwo does `git fetch` with `--depth` and `tag` work? I'm confused about the following behaviour:

After git shallow clone,

```bash
$ git fetch --depth 1 origin tag 1.5.5
 * [new tag]         1.5.5      -> 1.5.5
 * [new tag]         1.5.6      -> 1.5.6

$ git fetch origin tag 1.5.5
-- nothing more get fetched, and `git tag -l` still output the same:

$ git tag -l
1.5.5
1.5.6

$ git fetch --depth 2 origin tag 1.5.5
 * [new tag]         1.5.4      -> 1.5.4

$ git tag -l
1.5.4
1.5.5
1.5.6
```

IE. why does `git fetch --depth 1 origin tag` fetch tags upwards whereas `git fetch --depth 2 origin tag` fetch tags downwards?

Comment: to view what tag points to what commit : `git log --graph --oneline --all`. Could it be possible that `1.5.5` and `1.5.6` both point at the same commit ?

Comment: Ah, yes @LeGEC, indeed 1.5.5 and 1.5.6 both point at the same commit.