# How can be a subdirectory added as submodule in git

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-clone

I want to add to my repository a content from another repository, but not the whole repository just a part from sub-directory `My/Repo/Resources/Strings`
call like this is working for me and it is adding the whole repository to my project

```
git submodule add -b develop -- git@github:My/Repo.git
```

But I would like to have something like this:

```
git submodule add -b develop -- git@github:My/Repo/Resources/Strings.git
```

can It be achieved by some parameter? I do not really found anything on [git-submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). 
The error I received is : `fatal: clone of '...' into submodule path '...' failed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do it. `git submodule` tracks entire repositories as a submodules. You can try [sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11778551/7976758) on the submodule, that the best I could imagine.