# Shallow git submodule checkout using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-submodules

I have no problem doing this using git commands, as in [Set Git submodule to shallow clone & sparse checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238590/set-git-submodule-to-shallow-clone-sparse-checkout) but I have a project using Jenkins and I'm using the checkout() function in the Groovy Pipeline syntax. I can't find any option to pass the --depth option to the git submodule update commands.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use the extensions parameter in the checkout step:

```
checkout([
  $class: 'GitSCM', 
  branches: [[name: 'master']], 
  doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
  extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 0, noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: true]],
  submoduleCfg: [], 
  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@yourrepo.com:repo/repo.git']]])
```

If you are using the snippet generator, select `Additional Behaviors -> Advanced clone behaviors` to see the different options.  Hope that helps!

Comment: What does `depth: 0` do? Some resources, like [this one](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt/issues/241), suggest that depth 0 is invalid.

Comment: This method is not working for me. It still clones the complete repository.

Comment: It may not work if the Pipeline plugin or Git plugin version is old enough. I don't remember the details and it will take too much time to recover it, but I am sure that long time ago I reproduced such a problem that depth option did not work. The solution for me was to update. If you use depth 0 the value 1 is used anyway (I can see that from the command which Git plugin starts).

Comment: I think `depth: 0` doesn't make much sense, but [this code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/f563a47503e0072d7c41e2f44620be5ed50809df/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/extensions/impl/SubmoduleOption.java#L155) turns `depth: 0` into `depth: 1`. anyway.