# Sharing the details of a sparse submodule checkout such that future clones inherit those details

Tags: git, git-submodules, sparse-checkout

What I want to do:

- Add a submodule to an existing repo
- Do a sparse checkout on that repo (only populate a subset of the working tree)
- Make it so that when other people clone/pull that repo, the details of that sparse checkout are inherited (so they also, by default, only populate that subset of the working tree)

Is this possible?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11778551/6464224) suggests that that would not be possible ("sparse checkouts are exactly that: checkouts. You can't move files or share the settings"), but that was written in 2012 and things may have changed?

Comment: Things have not changed yet.

Comment: Yah, put the details in a or setup script. or a`make setup` target recipe or something.

Comment: Hi @jthill - I don't know what those words mean. If you think that is the closest thing to a solution that I'll find, would you be able to write an answer with more details and/or links to places I could learn more about those concepts?