Git-Submodules can ignore some folders?
Okay so I have two repo name X and Y. I have the same structure for both x->internal, product and y->internal, product. I want to use x's product in y and I would like to know what would happen if I created a release?
I added the submodule, but it has all the folders in it including the internal. I removed It and tried using a tag but won't helped at all. Also where I can read more about the submodules other than official documents.

Every submodule is a clone of a repository. To clone less use shallow submodules, To not checkout everything use sparse checkout. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238590/set-git-submodule-to-shallow-clone-sparse-checkout , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+shallow+sparse
