# Better practice with git involving existing remote repository subdirectories sharing with vendor

Tags: git, bitbucket

Our team has an existing remote repository R1 behind our company firewall that has following directory structure,

```
A\      <<------------- root of the repository R1, where "make project" is done;
  .git\
  B\
  C\
    CC1\
    CC2\
        CCC1\
        CCC2\       <<------------ share with vendor for code collaboration;
        CCC3\       <<------------ share with vendor for code collaboration;
        CCC4\       <<------------ share with vendor for code collaboration;
        CCC5\
    CC3\
  D\
  E\
```

We have a project with vendor that is outside of the firewall for collaborating on a project that involves the above 3 subdirectories of sources, CCC2, CCC3 and CCC4.  And the vendor and i would like use git for code sharing and code updates.  And we have agreed to use Bitbucket for hosting the private remote repository of codes in those 3 subdirectories.

Reading different approaches using git, we had come across nested git, git submodule and git subtree.  But what i'm using is neither, a crude method which involves manual merges.  In other words, i have created remote repository R2 in Bitbucket with source tree that is,

```
ZZZ\         <<------------ root of the repository R2;
    .git\
    CCC2\
    CCC3\
    CCC4\
```

And i would have 2 local repositories, one that is tracking R1 and the other for R2.  Then the workflow is that i would git pull first then do manual/hand merges between the two local repositories, and do the necessary git push to R1 and R2 to make each other repo changes appear on the other.  Yes, crude.

Question i have is, is there better, simpler approach?  The team had agreed to not rely on git submodule based on all our investigation on what it takes to use submodule feature.  And use of nested git is not favorable.  So, that sort of leaves us to investigating git subtree.  Our current try with subtree isn't quite working as expected, so still learning.

We had also looked at sparse checkout that creates outline of the R1 but with only the CCC2, CCC3 and CCC4 checked out.  That seem to work.  But when we push that to the Bitbucket repository R2, the R2 would be populated with all of the sources from R1.  So, something was not done right.

Ideally, what we would like to have is, more or less transparent pull/push between R1 and R2 remote repositories.  In other words, there would be a branch in R1 called "vendor-work", that will be used to pull (merge) vendor code changes from R2 to that branch, test it, and when appropriate merge into our project main/master branch.  In same token, the R2 has a branch called "company-work" with a pull request that the vendor will want to review before accepting the pull to their vendor working branch.  We haven't really thought about whether we need to merge repository R2's histories into R1, but the current thinking is, probably don't want the two repository histories to be merged into one, thus keeping them separate.

Thanks much.

Comment: In R1, under A/C/CC2, are any of the CCC{1,2,3,4,5} used for anything other then storing vendor code?  That is, for example, does `make project` in R1 depend on having CCCx?

Answer (score 0):

There's not any fined grained directory support for security in git, but there are various processes you can utilize.

The first question is, do you mind simply giving read access of the entire project to the vendor?  If this is not an option, you will need to use [submodules](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-submodule.html).  I personally think submodules are a bit of a pain so I would recommend avoiding this route.

If you don't mind giving them read access to the entire repository, then you can have the vendor [checkout only the sub-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180052/checkout-subdirectories-in-git/5394612#5394612) they need.  Then to control collaborative commits, you get the vendor to do pull requests so you can do a code review before merging their changes.