# How to manage WordPress themes or plugins with Git as part of a bigger repository?

Tags: git

In my repository, I have multiple folders with different stuff, say:

```
/HTML
/Scripts
/WordPress
    /Themes
        /redTheme
        /blueTheme
        /greenTheme
```

I have a local WordPress installation, with the standard structure:

```
/MyDevSite
    /wp-admin
    /wp-content
        /plugins
        /themes
```

What I need, is to directly checkout the folders `redTheme`, `blueTheme` and `greenTheme` into the folder `/MyDevSite/wp-content/themes`, edit them there, and check them back into the repository.

I've read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180052/checkout-subdirectories-in-git) that the way to do it should be sparse checkouts, and then read [this tutorial](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/) about the topic.

The problem is that when I enable sparse checkouts and add the folder to `.git/info/sparse-checkout` like this: `WordPress/Themes` it will check it *with* the folder structure from the repository:

```
/MyDevSite
    /wp-content
        /themes
            /WordPress
                /Themes
                    /redTheme
```

Now that's obviously not going to work. How can I check out a sub directory directly where I need it?