# How do I exclude a set of files from a local git repository?

Tags: git

I have a remote repository with several sub-directories like so:

```
/Client1
/Client2
/Server
```

I would like to create a local repository that only pulls one of these sub-directories (Server), and only pushes back changes to this directory. How can I do this?

I know I could split these sub-directories into multiple git repositories, but I'm trying to find a way to avoid changing the structure of the remote repository.

Comment: It seems that what you want is "sparse checkout" described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180052/checkout-subdirectories-in-git.

Answer (score 1):

You should use submodules for this purpose.

> ***`Submodules`*** ***allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated subdirectory*** of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

---

## ***`git submodule`***

Break your big project to sub projects as you did so far.
Now add each sub project to you main project using :

```
git submodule add <url>
```

Once the projected is added tot your repo you have to init and update it.

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Comment: Interesting- that's not quite what I'm looking for, because I do have to create three additional repositories, and then re-create the original, but maybe that's the way I'll have to go.