# git checkout and list changes on sub folder

Tags: git

Is there a way to just checkout (and later list all changes) on a sub folder of a big repo?

Example, this a huge repo: https://github.com/torvalds/linux

I'm not interested in checking out the whole repo and list through its million commits. So is there any way to just check out a specific folder and then list all commits for that folder only in the repo. For instance, just want to check the commits related to this folder: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net

Comment: See sparse-checkout, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout. To list the commits, use `git log -- <path>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkout subdirectories in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180052/checkout-subdirectories-in-git)