How to checkout just a single folder on a branch using git
How to checkout just a single folder on the default branch (say main) using git. I have the following structure in my git repository
repo/machine1/..
repo/machine2/..
repo/machine3/..

I would like to checkout just repo.git/machine1 and would want to avoid other folders

Take a look at git restore --source=main -- your/folder/, but there must be duplicates for this, did you research questions here? Also, I assumed you were talking about a repo you already cloned, but if you meant only cloning part of a repo, that's something else.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180052/checkout-subdirectories-in-git ???

@CardiDeMonacoJr Yes, it's the same one I was considering. Closing as duplicate of it in minutes if noone else finds a better one. Edit: Not that convinced. Answers mostly adress the sparse checkout scenario, which might not be what OP asks about.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+single+folder , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+subfolder
